# How do I deal with Inferi?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

When Dumbledore is trying to drink the potion and the Inferi keep coming up the hill and dragging you into the water, is there a way to keep the Inferi back and stop them from dragging you down the hill? 
So far I am only able to grab a drink of the potion, then wait to be dragged into the water. This means it takes me a while to drink all five cups. Can I hold them back in any way so I can drink them faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Reducto` (the orange spell) to constantly blast them back. That keeps them away long enough for Dumbledore to finish his drinking game.

Comment: Targeting with the spell doesn't work, but just casting it worked a treat.

Comment: I just hit the button repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to hit them with **Augmenti**.  The spray of water blasts them into pieces and gives Dumbledore the time he needs to drink the glass of water.

Also, whenever you are grabbed by the Inferi, if you switch to **Lumos Solem**, they let go of you for a brief amount of time, which is long enough for you to jump and run far enough away from them that you can switch back to a different spell that will destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

I used augmenti though my brother helped me I would kill them and he would gulp it down lol. So I recommend augmenti because you hold it down and it sprays its op.